# Dibujar rectángulos sobre una imagen con Graphics2D

Tags: java

Mi objetivo principal es dibujar estos rectángulos dando dos puntos mediante dos clicks de ratón, el problema es que ya tengo toda la base hecha, pero no dibuja los rectángulos. No sé si es que necesito actualizar algo que no actualizo, si estoy actualizando la imagen desde el principio...
El código es el siguiente:

```
package pruebas;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

´´´

´´´
public class Pruebas {

    ArrayList<Integer> array;
    JFrame me;
    Graphics2D g;
    ImagePanel panel;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Pruebas();
    }

    public Pruebas(){
        array = new ArrayList<>();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
             public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }

                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\Descargas\\IMG_20200304_103930.jpg"));
                    ImagePanel imgPane = new ImagePanel(img);
                    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imgPane);
                    JLabel report = new JLabel("...");

                    imgPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            Point panelPoint = e.getPoint();
                            Point imgContext = imgPane.toImageContext(panelPoint);
                            if(array.size()<4){
                                array.add(imgContext.x);
                                array.add(imgContext.y);
                                System.out.println("X: "+array.get(array.size()-2));
                                System.out.println("Y: "+array.get(array.size()-1));
                                System.out.println("Tamaño: "+array.size());
                            }
                            if(array.size()==4){
                                System.out.println("Tamaño: "+array.size());

                                g.drawRect(array.get(0), array.get(1), array.get(0)-array.get(2), array.get(1)-array.get(3));

                                array.clear();
                            }
                            report.setText("You clicked at " + panelPoint + " which is relative to the image " + imgContext);
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");

                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(scrollPane);
                    frame.add(report, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    if(g == null){
                        g = img.createGraphics();
                    }
                    if(me == null || panel == null){
                        panel = imgPane;
                        me = frame;
                    }
                    panel.revalidate();
                    panel.repaint();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Pruebas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImagePanel(BufferedImage img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        protected Point getImageLocation() {

            Point p = null;
            if (img != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                p = new Point(x, y);
            }
            return p;

        }

        public Point toImageContext(Point p) {
            Point imgLocation = getImageLocation();
            Point relative = new Point(p);
            relative.x -= imgLocation.x;
            relative.y -= imgLocation.y;
            return relative;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Point p = getImageLocation();
                g.drawImage(img, p.x, p.y, this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

En tiendo que quizá es cosa de no actualizar el panel que debo, o que la misma imagen reinicia al su contenido anterior, después debería guardar la imagen resultante, pero si no se puede tampoco es que pase nada.
Gracias por la ayuda.
No conozco muy bien cómo funcionan estas librerías y me estoy viendo negro.